# Verification and rigorousness of my own proof of transcendence of Liouville's number.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, transcendental-numbers

> **Theorem**: Liouville's number: $$L=\sum_{i=0}^\infty 10^{-i!}$$
>   is transcendental.

**Proof**: Denote
$$L_k=\sum_{i=0}^{k!} 10^{-i!}$$
We have:
$$L_1=0.1$$
$$L_2=0.11$$
$$L_3=0.110001$$
$$L_4=0.110001000000000000000001$$

We show that for sufficiently large $k$ powers of $L_k^n$ have the same digits in its decimal expansion as $L^n$. Assuming $L$ will be a solution to some polynomial, we will construct a polynomial with infinitely many solutions, which will give a contradiction.

**Lemma**: Let $n\in \Bbb{N}.$ Let $L_k^n=0,a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_{s}$ be the decimal expansion of $L_k^n$ and $L^n=0,b_1b_2b_3\ldots b_{s}\ldots$ the decimal expansion of $L^n$. There exists $k\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\forall i\leq k!:a_i=b_i$.

**Proof**: We have:
$$
L_k^n=(10^{-1}+10^{-2}+10^{-6}+\cdots+10^{-k!})\times$$
$$\times(10^{-1}+10^{-2}+10^{-6}+\cdots+10^{-k!})\times$$
$$\times10^{-1}+10^{-2}+10^{-6}+\cdots+10^{-k!}\times\cdots$$
The last digit, that is $a_s$ will be given by multiplying the $10^{-k!}$ terms $n$ times. That is: $10^{-nk!}$.We want $L^n$ to be very same at $b_s$.With the very same multiplication of $L^n$ term given by multiplying "the next", that is $10^{-(k+1)!}$ with $n-1$ terms $10^{-1}$ bigger. Thus following must hold:
$$10^{-nk!}>10^{-(n-1)}\cdot 10^{-(k+1)!}$$
equivalently:
$$nk!<n-1+(k+1)k!$$
Let $k=n-1$, then we obtain:
$$nk!<k+nk!$$
which is valid and we have shown such $k$ exists.

Let's make a little observation.
$$L^2=0.0121002200010000000000002200\ldots$$
$$L_1^2=0.01$$
$$L_2^2=0.0121$$
$$L_3^2=0.012100220001$$
$$L_4^2=0.012100220001000000000000220002$$

The argument is as follows: All the nonzero digits are further and further apart, which means the "next" non-zero digit, after raising the number to $n$-th power, won't play any role in creating "further" digits and thus modifying the previous digits. Thus we will end up having the very same digits, up to $a_s$.
For arbitrary big $n$ we can find some $k$ dependent on $n$ to have  arbitrarily big "sections" of zeros in $L_k^n$. Even when multiplying $L_k^n$ by arbitrarily big constant, we can still have arbitrarily big "sections" of zeros. Thus if $L_k$ can approximate $L$, then $P(L_k)$ can approximate $P(L)$, where $P$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients.

Now, suppose that $L$ is a solution to polynomial $P(x)=p_0+p_1x+\ldots+...p_nx^n$ and some other polynomial $Q(x)=q_0+q_1x+\ldots+...q_mx^m$. Now compare $P$ and $Q$ when approximating by $L_k$. Denote $n=\max\{\deg P, \deg Q\}$. By the lemma we are able to find $k$, dependent on $n$ such that $P(L_k)=Q(L_k)$
but also $\forall j\in \Bbb{N}, j\geq k$ we have that:
$$P(L_j)=Q(L_j)$$
Thus the equation
$$P-Q=0$$ has infinitely many solutions. But it can have at most $n$. We conclude that $L$ must be transcendental.

What I would like to know is whether my proof is actually valid and can be taken seriously. I would like to hear someone else's opinion on what could be done better, more rigorous, etc. Actually, I would like to make the proof as rigorous as possible, but still elementary as it is.

Comment: Something I don’t understand in the proof of your Lemma. You only work on $a_s, b_s$ while your claim is about $a_i,b_i$ for all $i \le k!$.

Comment: And also why do you work with two polynomials $P,Q$? If $P$ exists with $L$ as a root, any multiple of $P$ will also have $L$ as a root.

Comment: I'm essentially showing that there is arbitrary long section of zeroes. What I need to show that there is no interferetion between consecutive digits. The fact that all others $a_i$'s will remain the same for $L^n$ And $L_k^n$ is obvious.

Comment: At least this is not obvious to me! A good argument of why it is obvious would be welcome.

Comment: Let me edit. Might take a while.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net see my edited post. Also made a little correction for $L_k$ the sum is not up to $k$ but up to $k!$.

Comment: Yeah, well i work with 2 polynomials to estabilish the equation with infinitely many solutions. Is there a way to do it with just one?